# How to resolve "Page not available" error in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, error, lightning-community

I am getting "Page not available" error while opening a community page containing a specific lightning(aura) component in one of our implementation. The error screen is attached below. **URL: ** *https://{communitydomain}/s/warrantyrenewal*

**Implementation overview:**

I have built two community pages(in community builder - not VF pages) which includes aura components in it and are used to display to community users, when navigating from object list view. The redirection happens from "New" button which is a custom component built for community. The object access is proper and community user has create access for the same. The error occurs for the user only for first time, but on page reload page opens up correctly.

**solutions/recommendations tried for solving the error:**

- I have checked for access check errors of which there were none.
- Opened the component using lightning debug mode, but didn't find any specific error which might cause the page loading issue.
- Have tried getting in touch with salesforce support, but they were not that helpful.

Any pointers to help getting it resolved would be much appreciated.

[image: page error]

Comment: Can you put the URL as well? Usually the VF pages in community have the community name in the path.

Comment: @manjit5190, URL basically goes like this: https://{communitydomain}/s/warrantyrenewal. I have updated the question with same. Basically its not a VF page, but built using community builder where the aura component has been dragged and added.